# PostAsync does not add cookies

Tags: c#

I have a website using web Security and another web system which is built in asp.net Identity, Both the applications are having same credentials of user, My requirement is when I sign in in my web security application then through redirects or something, i can get logged into the other website as well using credentials user provide.

I have tried redirecting and then putting the login credentials in control and triggering the submit but its not working.

```
//Here is code for redirecting to external url
Response.Redirect("http://localhost:2534/Account/LogOn?UserName=" + m.Username + "&Password=" + m.Password, false);
```

next thing I tried is to call the logon post method directly from my website and its still not working

```
private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "UserName",  "Username"},
    { "Password", "Password" },
    { "RememberMe", "true" }
};

var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
var response = await client.PostAsync(http://localhost:2534/Account/LogOn", content);
var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: provide a minimal, reproducible exmple

Comment: The response will contain any cookies, you must add them to a CookieContainer and assign that to your next call.